# Will outermost .catch() work for all chained / nested promisses?

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, promise, redux

I have a bit of a long login process that relies on 3 api calls that looks like this at the moment:

```
export const authenticationSignIn = (email, password) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST });
    apiAccountStatus(email, password)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const status = data.status;
      if (status === 'ACCOUNT_CREATED') {
        apiSignIn(email, password)
        .then(({ data: sessionData }) => {
          apiIndexAccounts()
          .then(({ data: accountsData }) => {
            dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS });
            window.router.transitionTo('/dashboard/home');
          });
        });
      } else if (status === 'SOMETHING ELSE') {
        // TODO: HANDLE SOMETHING ELSE
      }
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
      dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE });
      dispatch(notificationShow('ERROR', response.data.type));
    });
  };
```

As you can see this function is quiet verbose, but each nested api call relies on data returned from previous and I am trying to clean this up as much as possible (dispatch bits are redux specific, but these essentially fire whatever is passed in). At the end you will see a `catch` statement, my question is will this catch statement work for all of the promisses or only `apiAccountStatus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the end you will see a catch statement, my question is will this catch statement work for all of the promises?

No, it only works for the outer promise, the one returned by the `then` call. This needs to be rejected for the `catch` callback to be activated. To get this promise rejected, either `apiAccountStatus(…)` must reject or the `then` callback must throw an exception or *return a promise that will be rejected*.

This last thing is what you were missing - you were creating more promises inside that `then` callback, but you weren't `return`ing them so that they will not chain. You have to do

```
export function authenticationSignIn(email, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST });
    apiAccountStatus(email, password)
    .then(({data: {status}}) => {
      if (status === 'ACCOUNT_CREATED') {
        return apiSignIn(email, password)
//      ^^^^^^
        .then(({ data: sessionData }) => {
          return apiIndexAccounts()
//        ^^^^^^
          .then(({ data: accountsData }) => {
            dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS });
            window.router.transitionTo('/dashboard/home');
          });
        });
      } else if (status === 'SOMETHING ELSE') {
        // TODO: HANDLE SOMETHING ELSE
      }
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
      dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE });
      dispatch(notificationShow('ERROR', response.data.type));
    });
  };
}
```